# Hint OPTION (FAST n) does not make any difference for me

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a large table and query from it ordered by a non-indexed column.
I do it declaring a cursor, because I need the rows for paging, that means the first N rows first, then maybe the next N rows later.

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR select col1,col2 from table order by col2;
```

I know that Sql Server can optimize to give the first N rows fast because if I say TOP(N), then it gives it back very fast, eg:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR select TOP(@N) col1,col2 from table order by col2;
```

I've read that I can ask the server to give the first N rows fast, so I've tried it:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR select TOP(@N) col1,col2 from table order by col2 OPTION (FAST @N);
```

Unfortunately no effect, i.e. it is as slow as without the hint.
Why?
How can it be solved?

Answer (score 3):

The `FAST` option doesn't make any difference in the query that you are applying it to.

A query where it would make any difference would typically have several different joins, so that the query planner would have some different choices for how to retrieve the data. When joining data there are ways that are faster overall, and ways that return the first rows quickly but are slower overall. If you specify the `FAST` option to a query where those choices exist, the query planner will choose the one that returns the first rows more quickly.

When you are sorting on a non-indexed column that will always be slow, as the entire table has to be read before the first row can be returned. Adding an index is really the only way to make that query any faster.

Comment: Not exactly. The table can be read within 1 sec. The cursor starts to give records after 5 secs. If I ask e.g. TOP(10), it comes back very fast. If there are null values in col2 of read rows they can be put into the ordered resultset. If I simply run the query without cursor, it behaves how I would like it from the cursor.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying there but perhaps you could any new information to the question. As already stated, FAST only makes a difference in certain circumstances. I suggest you check the query plan with and without FAST (and you'll probably find there is no difference)